# Fatal error: Call to undefined method PDO::close()

Tags: php, pdo

I have got that error and the line was this:

```
public function __destruct() {
        $this->db->close();
    }
```

I use PDO, is this the problem, does the PDO driver not recognize this function? If yes, what is its equivalent in PDO?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A PDO connection is closed by [destroying its object:](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php)

> The connection remains active for the lifetime of that PDO object. To close the connection, you need to destroy the object by ensuring that all remaining references to it are deleted--you do this by assigning NULL to the variable that holds the object. If you don't do this explicitly, PHP will automatically close the connection when your script ends.

so

```
$this->db = null;
```

should work.

Answer (score 2):

PDO doesn't have an explicit "close" function. You can simply do

```
$this->db = null
```

to destroy the object, which will automatically clean up the connections.

Answer (score 2):

You close it by putting the handle to `null`

From php.net:

```
<?php
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass);
// use the connection here

// and now we're done; close it
$dbh = null;
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Setting the PDO variable to null closes the connection and frees all related memory.

An alternative to is to use closeCursor to close the connection with the server but leave the PDO Object around.

> "[closeCursor](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.closecursor.php) frees up the connection to the server so that other
> SQL statements may be issued, but leaves the statement in a state that
> enables it to be executed again."

That means you can continue to run fetch() et al, even though the connection has been freed.

Again, not the same as mysql_close(), but nonetheless incredibly useful.

Answer (score 0):

PDO doesn't have a close method.  To destroy the connection the PDO object represents, destroy all references to the object itself with unset().

Answer (score 0):

PDO hasnt close method. i think you can try to unset $this->db, this disconnect automatically