# Creating a separate PDO connect method to prevent code repetition

Tags: php, pdo

My code:

```
class db_mysqls
{

private $host;
private $user;
private $password;
private $db_name;
private $port;



/** Constructor sets the object of DB_MySQL*/
public function __construct($host, $port, $user, $password, $db_name)
{
    $this->host = $host;
    $this->port = $port;
    $this->user = $user;
    $this->password = $password;
    $this->db_name = $db_name;

}



/**getFromDB($statement) gets information from DB*/
public function getFromDB($query)
{

    try
    {
        $con = new PDO("mysql:host=$this->host;port=$this->port;dbname=$this->db_name", $this->user, $this->password);
        $con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }
    catch (PDOException $e)
    {
        echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }


    try
    {
        $resp = $con->query($query);
        return $resp;

    }
    catch (PDOException $e)
    {
        echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }

}
```

I want to create a separate method in the same class `class db_mysqls` that will handle the connection.

Something like that:

```
private $con;

private function connect()
{
   global $con;
    try
    {
      $con = new PDO("mysql:host=$this->host;port=$this->port;dbname=$this->db_name", $this-  >user, $this->password);
    $con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }
     catch (PDOException $e)
    {
        echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
}

    /**getFromDB($statement) gets information from DB*/
public function getFromDB($query)
{
    global $con;

    connect(); //the call to the new function that handles connection.

    try
    {
        $resp = $con->query($query);
        return $resp;

    }
    catch (PDOException $e)
    {
        echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }

}
```

The problem is that I get disconnected as soon as I get out of `connect()` scope, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Connecting every time you need to do a query doesn't seem reasonable to me.

Comment: This code is messy. Why use `global` in a class??

Comment: I used global to save the connection

Comment: @user4035 I don't understand why not what should  do instead? I need to set a connection before query and when I'm out of scope connection is lost.

Comment: @Canttouchit Your approach is absolutely incorrect. I am writing an answer now, explaining, what is wrong and how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use OOP approach, you must encapsulate the data inside your class. Watch SICP lectures 2 - 4, where data abstraction is explained in details. Don't use global variables inside your class functions - it will lead to a horrible, messy code. Look at my code. It stores the connection inside the private variable and connects only once - when the object is created in constructor function.

### class.php

```
<?php
class db_mysqls
{

    private $host;
    private $user;
    private $password;
    private $db_name;
    private $port;
    private $connection;

/** Constructor sets the object of DB_MySQL*/
    public function __construct($host, $port, $user, $password, $db_name)
    {
        $this->host = $host;
        $this->port = $port;
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->password = $password;
        $this->db_name = $db_name;

        $this->connect();
    }


    private function connect()
    {
        try
        {
            $this->connection = new PDO("mysql:host=$this->host;port=$this->port;dbname=$this->db_name", $this->user, $this->password);
            $this->connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        }
        catch (PDOException $e)
        {
            echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    public function getFromDB($query)
    {
        try
        {
            $resp = $this->connection->query($query);
            return $resp;
        }
        catch (PDOException $e)
        {
            echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

### script.php

```
include_once('class.php);
$db = new db_mysqls("localhost", 3306, "user", "", "test");
$query = "SELECT * FROM Document";
$result = $db->getFromDB($query);
while($row = $result->fetch())
{
    var_dump($row);
}
```

### test database

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Document`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `Document` (
  `DataID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Description` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`DataID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--
-- Dumping data for table `Document`
--

LOCK TABLES `Document` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `Document` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `Document` VALUES (1,'This is document 1');
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `Document` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

Running `php script.php` will print the rows from Document table. Actually, I don't see any reason in creating such a class - just using PDO object will be ok.

Comment: Do i need to worry about implementation of disconnect method from DB as well?

Comment: @Canttouchit If you want, we can create a destructor in class, that will disconnect when the object is destroyed.

Comment: @Canttouchit As this answer says: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5772626/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-method-pdoclose, the PDO object disconnects when it is destroyed. So, there is no need to explicitly write a destructor - you will be disconnected automatically when your class object is destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. First of all in both codes you are connecting every time you need to perform a query which is really inefficient. Just follow the PDO example and connect inside the constructor:

```
public function __construct($host, $port, $user, $password, $db_name) {
    $this->host = $host;
    $this->port = $port;
    $this->user = $user;
    $this->password = $password;
    $this->db_name = $db_name;
    try {
        $this->pdo = new \PDO("mysql:host=$this->host;port=$this->port;dbname=$this->db_name", $this->user, $this->password);
        $con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    } catch (\PDOException $e) {
        // connection failed
    }
}
```

With the above code we are going to save the `PDO` object inside a class variable called `$pdo` that we can easily retrieve inside every instance method of the class via `$this->pdo`:

```
public function getFromDB($query) {
    try {
        $resp = $this->pdo->query($query);
        return $resp;
    } catch (\PDOException $e) {
        // query failed
    }
}
```

Second of all: never ever use globals. They are bad, they have been proven to be bad and you surely don't need them here.

Comment: I was also downvoted without any good reason. I don't think, that my answer and recommendation of using data abstraction is something bad. I am upvoting you, your arguments seem absolutely correct.

Comment: @user4035, I wasn't sure if it was [Your Common Sense](http://stackoverflow.com/users/285587/your-common-sense) or not to have downvoted, but now that he posted an answer I'm 99% sure it's him that downvoted both. It's in his... *style*.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to know about classes - they have their own "global" variables that belongs to that class only. So, them you have to use.

Just change `global $con` to `protected $con` and address this variable as `$this->con`
This way you won't need no dedicated connect() method, as well as useless one-time variables like $host and others, which will **indeed** let you avoid a lot of code repetitions.

Also avoid using try..catch if you aren't going to take any action. All other codes spoils your error reporting instead of making it helpful

```
class db_mysqls
{
    protected $con;

    /** Constructor sets the object of DB_MySQL*/
    public function __construct($user, $password, $db_name, 
                                $host='localhost', $port = 3306, charset = 'utf8')
    {
        $dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db_name;port=$port;charset=$charset";
        $opt = array(
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
            PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC
        );
        $this->con = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password, $opt);
    }

    /**getFromDB($statement) gets information from DB*/
    public function getFromDB($query)
    {
        return $this->con->query($query);
    }
}
```

that's all the code you need

```
$db = new db_mysqls("root", "", "test");
$result = $db->getFromDB("SELECT * FROM table");
```